# Extract last lines from CSV files and put it in another file with File name in Python

Tags: python, csv, append, python-3.6

I have a list of CSV files in a directory:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

Example contents of files are:

```
value1  value2  value3
377298  128203  383929
365173  289201  287392
```

I need to pick each last lines from each files and put it in another CSV:

```
files   value1  value2  value3
file1   365173  289201  287392
file2   362829  273829  372910
```

Any help will really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `os` module to get a list of filenames and then write an initial header line to the out `.csv` and then for each file in the directory, write the last line of that file concatenated onto the name of that file with a tab character as a separator.

```
import os
dir_name = 'the_directory'
with open('the_csv.csv', 'w') as out_handler:
    out_handler.write('\t'.join(['files', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'])+'\n')
    for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
        with open(os.path.join(dir_name, file)) as in_handler:
            out_handler.write(file[:file.index('.')] + '\t' + in_handler.readlines()[-1])
```

---

And a full test:

```
$ more the_directory/*
::::::::::::::
the_directory/a.csv
::::::::::::::
value1  value2  value3
377298  128203  383929
365173  289201  287392
::::::::::::::
the_directory/b.csv
::::::::::::::
value1  value2  value3
377298  128203  383929
365987  289123  287456
$ python -q
>>> import os
>>> dir_name = 'the_directory'
>>> with open('the_csv.csv', 'w') as out_handler:
...     out_handler.write('\t'.join(['files', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'])+'\n')
...     for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
...         with open(os.path.join(dir_name, file)) as in_handler:
...             out_handler.write(file + '\t' + in_handler.readlines()[-1])
... 
27
29
29
>>> 
$ cat the_csv.csv 
files   value1  value2  value3
b.csv   365987  289123  287456
a.csv   365173  289201  287392
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I want the first column to be `file1`, not `file1.csv`.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the top code to slice up to the dots in the filename to remove the `.csv` extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob.iglob` to find the files, and `pd.read_csv` to read each one.

For example,

```
 import glob
 import pandas as pd
 list_last_values=[]
 for csv in glob.iglob('Path\\*.csv'):
     data=pd.read_csv(csv)
     list_last_values.append(pd.DataFrame(data.loc[len(data)-1,:]).T)

 df_last_values=pd.concat(list_last_values)`
```